# Configure 'mail' command to send external email when servers domain name is used

Tags: email, postfix

I have **postfix** and **mail** installed on my server.

The following command works fine

```
$mail aj@xyz.com
```

But if I use this command

```
$mail aj@mydomain.com
```

The system thinks I am trying to send a local email to the user 'aj'. How can set **mail** to send emails to aj@mydomain.com externally?

The output from /etc/mailname is

```
$cat /etc/mailname 
mydomain.com
```

The output from /etc/mail.rc

```
$cat /etc/mail.rc
set ask askcc append dot save crt  
ignore Received Message-Id Resent-Message-Id Status Mail-From Return-Path Via Delivered-To
```

Answer (score 5):

From [1] pg 832

> Another parameter we should set is mydestination, which specifies the
>   mail domains that are local.

The changes which are relevant to my question:

Change the mydestination setting in /etc/postfix/main.cf to be blank.

```
mydestination =
```

run

```
sudo postfix reload
```

[1] Unix and Linux system administration handbook, 4ed, 0-13-148005-7, 978-0-13-148005-6